# Machine restart resetting my bashrc to default

Tags: bash, debian

I added some changes to .bashrc. But whenever I restart my machine it resets the file to default and my changes are gone.

What might cause this?
What is the solution?

My OS is debian11

Comment: Are you running from a "Live CD" type installation? Which `.bashrc` are you editing (in what directory)? Is this mounted from a filesystem stored on disk or a transient one in memory? If you create a file such as `.mytest` alongside your problematic `.bashrc` does this file get deleted when you reboot?

Comment: @roaima ~/.bashrc is the location. it is mounted on filesystem stored on disk. I have not tried the last option you suggested. Let me try that. Thanks.

Comment: `~` isn't a location. Or if you think it is, please let us know the result of `echo "$HOME"`

Comment: @roaima /home/<username>/.bashrc is the location.

Comment: @roaima I tried the last option and created a custom file. That remains in place but .bashrc reset to default again

Comment: Is this a stock standard vanilla install of Debian bullseye? Does this only happen when you reboot? i.e. if you logout and log back in, do your changes "stick"

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes it is vanilla install and it only happens on reboot